# Modelling Typeclasses in C++

Tags: c++, haskell, functional-programming, typeclass

Is it possible to implement Haskell typeclasses in C++? If yes, then how?

Comment: What are Haskell-like typeclasses?

Comment: Noah, Sorry but I don't know how else to express it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a few papers on this, which might be useful as background reading:

- [C++ templates/traits versus Haskell type classes](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.78.2151), Sunil Kothari ,  Martin Sulzmann
- [A Comparative Study of Language Support for Generic Programming](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.61.9949), Ronald Garcia ,  Jaakko Järvi ,  Andrew Lumsdaine ,  Jeremy Siek ,  Jeremiah Willcock

Comment: Am I the only one to notice that the OP's name is similar to the name of the first author of "C++ templates/traits versus Haskell type classes" ?

Comment: +1 for the second link, a categorization of the required features is very interesting indeed.

Comment: First paper: "C++ templates/traits versus Haskell type classes". There is an error at page 9 (Example 6), code is expressed in the body of a `struct`. It seems to me that the author have only an approximative knowledge of C++ and this shows in the examples.

Answer (score 3):

The similar mechanism in C++ is called "concepts". The idea is to define a typeclass by defining the requirements of any type belonging to that class. C++ iterators make extensive use of concepts, and C++0x had intended to support direct syntax for them (rather than the indirect template tricks to perform concept checks C++ currently employs), but it appears this support has been dropped from the standard.